# why should I not use find optimizations?

Tags: unix, optimization, find

I read in the manual and info pages the sections about optimization levels in the `find` command and I cannot understand why I should *not* use the most aggressive optimization level.

The only relevant sentences I found was (from the `man find` version `4.4.2`):

> Conversely, optimisations that prove to be reliable, robust and effective may be enabled at lower optimisation levels over time.
>
> The findutils test suite runs all the tests on find at each optimisation level and ensures that the result is the same.

If I understood well, it's about proofing the right behaviour of `find` through findutils but, this test suit ensures that all otimization levels are giving the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing this sentence:

> The cost-based optimiser has a fixed idea of how likely any given test is to succeed.

That means if you have a directory with highly atypical contents (e.g. a lot of named pipes and very few "regular" files), the optimizer may actually *worsen* the performance of your query (in this case by assuming `-type f` is more likely to succeed than `-type p` when the reverse is true).  In a situation like this, you're better off hand-optimizing it, which is only really possible at `-O1` or `-O2`.

Even ignoring this issue, the fixed costs of the cost based optimizer are difficult to get right.  There are multiple pieces of hardware and software involved (the hard disk, the kernel, the filesystem) which all do some caching and optimization of their own.  As a result, it is very hard to predict how expensive different operations will be, even relative to one another (e.g. we know `readdir(2)` is cheaper than `stat(2)`, but we don't know *how much cheaper*).  This means cost-based optimization is not always guaranteed to produce the best optimization even assuming typical filesystem contents.  The lower optimization levels allow you to hand-tune your query by trial and error, which may be more reliable, if more laborious.